# Why can't handle the exception from another forms and services?

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, .net-core

I'm trying to catch unhandled exceptions in my winforms app. So, I've read all topics of this and write as said there. But I can't handle exceptions from another forms or services of my app. It handles only exceptions in class program. I can't understand why. Any advice.

```
 internal static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(UnhandledExceptionHAndler);
            Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
            Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

            ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterModule<ServiceModule>();

            using var container = builder.Build();
            var form = container.Resolve<BookShopForm>();

            Application.Run(form);
            Environment.Exit(-1);
        }

        static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            // Do logging
            ShowExceptionDetails(e.Exception);
        }

        static void UnhandledExceptionHAndler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
        {
            ShowExceptionDetails(args.ExceptionObject as Exception);
        }

        static void ShowExceptionDetails(Exception Ex)
        {
            // Do logging of exception details
            MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message, Ex.TargetSite.ToString(),
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```